# Sprite is null after getDefinitionByName seems to be working okay

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code

```
_object = getDefinitionByName("embeds."+_fMapHex.tile);
_sprite = new _object as Sprite;
trace(_sprite, _object.toString(), _mapHex.clip);
```

this is the output of the trace

```
null [class tunnel] [object Sprite]
```

and I don't understand why, am I missing something obvious?

I already tried  the object as Class, same behavior. The Sprite is a Starling Sprite, I don't know if it makes any difference…  the embeds  are some SWF files embedded as regular movie clips

Please let me know your thoughts

Thanks!

Comment: it just mean that your new _object cast as Sprite is null - so it is not Sprite - what is base class for tunnel? And casting as Class is just not right:) instance will never be a Class:) you could try without casting or cast it as DisplayObject

Comment: thanks for your reply! tunnel extends flash.display.MovieClip

Comment: if I add a dummy as a regular flash movie clip like so

_object = getDefinitionByName("embeds."+_fMapHex.ground_tile);
var _dummy:* = new _object as MovieClip;
_sprite = _dummy as Sprite;
trace(_dummy, _sprite, _object.toString(), _mapHex.clip);

 then the dummy looks as expected
[object tunnel] null [class tunnel] [object Sprite]

 so I'm wondering if it Starling related…

Comment: Could be:) maybe you expect flash.display.Sprite but Starling has it's own Sprite - check the imports maybe you accidently imported wrong class

Comment: that is exactly what the problem was, Starling Sprite is different than flash Sprite :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure that you are using classes from correct packages, Starling Sprite is different to flash Sprite. 
Also when casting returns null it may give you a hint that object is not the type you are trying to cast to.